# Запятая перед и после «совершенно случайно» и перед «недавно»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> И вот(,) недавно(,) совершенно случайно (,) я встретил ту девушку.

Где нужно поставить знаки препинания?

Answer (score 2):

По общим правилам здесь нет никаких знаков препинания: **вот** - частица, **недавно** и **случайно** не являются однородными, так как обозначают разные по смыслу обстоятельства образа действия.

*И вот недавно совершенно случайно я встретил ту девушку.*

Однако "совершенно случайно" может быть воспринято как пояснение, и тогда оно обособляется с двух сторон:

*И вот недавно, совершенно случайно, я встретил ту девушку*.
Возможно обособить как пояснение и "недавно":

*И вот, недавно, совершенно случайно  я встретил ту девушку.*

Правда, это выглядит очень уж субъективно, как авторская пунктуация, потому что частица обычно относится к следующему за ней слову и не отделяется от него.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант постановки запятых:

**И вот недАвно, совершенно случАйно, я встретил ту дЕвушку.**

Обособленное обстоятельство имеет значение дополнительного пояснения.

В этом случае обеспечивается наилучший вариант произношения.

При отсутствии обособления мы имеет такое предложение: *И вот недавно совершенно случайно // я встретил ту девушку.*

Произнести в одну фразу "*И вот недавно совершенно случАйно*"  (с одним ударением) довольно затруднительно.

Answer (score 0):

В Нацкорпусе нашлось 5 вхождений, в одном из них слова "совершенно случайно" выделены  запятыми. На мой взгляд, это говорит о том, что веделение возможно, но не обязательно, оно должно выражать отношение автора (основная это информация или дополнительная).

> Я тут недавно совершенно случайно узнала, что Верлибр после этого случая вызвал Перхоту на дуэль. [Виорель Ломов. Музей // «Октябрь», 2002]
>
> Недавно совершенно случайно в новой повести Даниила Гранина «Вечера с Петром Великим» нашел определение состояния, в котором находились многие из нас в пору переустройства кинематографа. [Армен Медведев. Территория кино (1999-2001)]
>
> Представляешь, сказал я ему, недавно совершенно случайно вслушалась в программу «Время», а там как раз передавали насчет этого случая с Папой Римским. [Дина Рубина. Двойная фамилия (1986)]
>
> Тут я недавно совершенно случайно увидел свою физиономию, а последний раз это было в сентябре, в день свидания с Санькой. [Юлий Даниэль. Письма из заключения (1966-1970)]
>
> Скажите мне, мой друг, что вы думаете о книге, которая недавно, совершенно случайно, попала в мои руки и о которой я не успел составить себе представления, так как прочел всего несколько страниц? [Г. А. Газданов. Пробуждение (1966)]

Comment: Мы строим наши предложение по схеме "семантика - выбор структуры - знаки препинания", поэтому сравнивать надо предложения сходной структуры, а в Ваших примерах таких нет. Всё это сложные предложения, у них совершенно иная расстановка ударений. А здесь простое предложение.  Вообще говоря. важно всё: сколько слов, как они расположены. Сравнить: Недавно /я совершенно случайно /встретил эту девушку, и мы с ней наконец познакомились. Здесь нет обособления (дополнительное пояснение не выражено), и структура другая, предложение разбито на произносительные части, удобные для чтения